# AngularJS, GAE, Python Flask and CORS

Tags: python, angularjs, google-app-engine, flask

I am new to AngularJS and I have the following:

- Python Flask REST services running on Google App Engine (GAE)
- AngularJS front-end running on GoDaddy

I have a REST service that I'm trying to call from my AngularJS GUI. If I access my REST service with curl, everything works just fine, as expected. So I'm confident that my REST code is not the issue. I know that I need to account for CORS so I have added this to my **server** side flask code:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE, OPTIONS')
    return response
```

My complete **client-side** code looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }]);


    var formData = {
        txtFirstName: "default",
        txtLastName: "default",
        txtEmail: "default"
    };

    $scope.save = function() {
        formData = $scope.form;
    };

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        console.log("posting data....");
        formData = $scope.form;

        $http.post('http://myserviceURL/promo', JSON.stringify(formData)).success(function(){
            console.log(formData);
        });
    };

});
```

But this keeps on generating the error of:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myservicelocation/promo. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63343' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

At this point I have no idea if my issue is client-side or server-side - I thought the code above should account for both?!?!?! Can someone please post an end-to-end solution of what the headers should look like for both the client and server side?

Comment: HTTP status code 500?  That means the request failed and probably didn't run your `after_request()` call.  Check your server logs and see what blew up.

Comment: @BrentWashburne thank you. As I said, if I use curl, the server-side code works fine. So could it be a problem with how I'm posting from the Angular file? I'm just using a simple http.post - are there better ways to try?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like your `$http.post()` call is different than your `curl` request.  Use your browser to examine the actual request's contents.

Comment: in chrome you can right click on a request and get it as a curl, try that.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood that's very interesting. Where exactly would I right-click? Like in the JavaScript console or?

Comment: on the actual request in the network tab, copy as cURL

Comment: @PaulCollingwood thanks I will have to try that. As I'm working with this more and more I'm starting to think that the JSON data isn't properly attached on the client side. So I think that looking at the actual curl request from chrome is definitely on the right track.